# How do I grab the fields of the generic class I pass into a constructor in java

Tags: java, class, generics, constructor

Okay, I have a minHeap class I want to sort by class fields. I realize that the generics are erased at runtime and there are a few workarounds and I do have some options with reflections library but quite frankly I am still pretty confused. Essentially what I am trying to do is, for example,

This would be in another class

```
minHeap<Tuple<Integer>> heap = new minHeap<Tuple<Integer>>();
```

Then, hopefully, `heap.sortBy("fieldName");`

Right now these are my fields/constructor for the minHeap class.

```
class minHeap<E> implements heapInterface<E> { 
    int size;
    E[] data;
    private Comparator<E> comparator; 

    public minHeap(Comparator<E> compare) {
        size = 0;
        this.data = (E[]) new Object[10];
        this.comparator = compare;
    }
}
```

I am not sure if I am supposed to pass the class type in the parameters of my constructor and then use the reflections library to pull all the fields or what. Any more clarity on this would be very much appreciated. (PS if anyone else knows how to use a comparator inside that class rather than having to pass one in I would appreciate the advice on that as well.)

Comment: You're constructing the `minHeap<E>` (which, in keeping with established convention, you really should call `MinHeap<E>` with a  capital `M`)  with a `Comparator<E>`.  The comparator is **all you need** to define the sort order for the heap.

Comment: I think you’re missing my point here. I am trying to understand how to pull the fields from the Tuple class (that I have made with arbitrary fields) into my minHeap class and sort the heap by those fields. So if Tuple had a string field and a integer field I could write a method to sort by either of those fields. Does that make sense? My main question is pulling fields into the minHeap class

Comment: Pulling fields from the Tuple class, and then comparing them, is what a `Comparator` does.  The heap then uses the `Comparator` to compare various Tuples and makes its sorting decisions based on the results reported by the `Comparator`.  To sort by a different field (or even a combination of fields), you just supply a different `Comparator` implementation that makes its comparisons based on that particular field (or combination of fields)..